# Does a Virtual Machine Manager (VMM) and a hypervisor refer to the same thing?

Tags: virtualization

I am reading an operating systems textbook that never uses the term *hypervisor*, it only uses the term *virtual machine manager (VMM)*. However, when I try to gather more information on the internet about virtualization, I never see VMM mentioned and only hypervisor. They seem to refer to the same thing... Is this correct?

Comment: Which textbook is this?

Comment: [Operating Systems in Depth](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Operating+Systems+In+Depth%3A+Design+and+Programming-p-9780471687238)

Comment: The professor learned his craft a long time ago.  Hypervisor is the modern term, started getting used in 2006 when virtualization became possible on Intel and AMD processors.  It avoids the ambiguity of VMM (monitor vs manager).

Comment: What is the different between a monitor and a manager? @HansPassant

Comment: Generally, manager, monitor, supervisor, executive, etc., are interchangeable in programming circles.  When you have to write a thing that controls other things, just pick whichever of those names you like and which hasn't been used yet in your system. Also, "monitor" is an earlier name for "OS kernel".  See, for example, the DEC TOPS-10 Monitor, or the SDS 940 Timesharing System Monitor.  Even "virtual machine" has a different meaning than it used to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure the terms are used consistently by everyone, but in my experience, the distinction is that the hypervisor is the low-level software that exercises direct control over VMs, including CPU state management, guest enter/exit, memory protection, etc. The VMM is the component that virtualizes system resources for the guest, including virtual devices (e.g., storage, network, and graphics), and guest memory allocation. The VMM may run in a guest itself, and it may run in user mode. There may be a separate instance of the VMM for each guest, but there is only one hypervisor in a system (except for some complex situations that I'm not going to go into here). The details of which component is responsible for what is highly implementation dependent, and in some VMM architectures, they may be the same component, so it could be called either name.

Comment: This is a great insight. I was wondering, perhaps you know of some materials where this difference is better explained? Not to hijack this question, but just a few hours ago I asked basically the [same question on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/1013404/what-is-the-difference-between-a-hypervisor-and-a-vmm-virtual-machine-monitor), then stumbled upon this. Most of the materials on the web refer to VMM & hypervisors as the same thing, yet I've also seen (more reputable) examples where they are explicitly separated, but without meaningful explanation. This drives me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't read book so cannot comment unless you give some specific extract from book.

In general VMM refers to Virtual Machine Manger that's tool to manage virtual machine from some server (Hypervisor) Local / remote.

Hypervisor on other hand refers to severer which is capable of running  Virtual Machines on them.